# json-patch-1.13.jar: CVE-2021-4279(9.8) Quarkus 2.15.2.Final

Tags: quarkus

The dependency check is now failing on json-patch:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.owasp:dependency-check-maven:7.4.3:check (default-cli) on project ins-app:  [ERROR]  [ERROR] One or more dependencies were identified with vulnerabilities that have a CVSS score greater than or equal to '8.0':  [ERROR]  [ERROR] json-patch-1.13.jar: CVE-2021-4279(9.8) CVE is https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-4279`

The fix PR is probably here (Starcounter-Jack/JSON-Patch@7ad6af4). But it is another repository?

https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-patch/issues/144

Answer (score 1):

It is actually a bug on DependencyCheck, one that was already addressed:

https://github.com/jeremylong/DependencyCheck/issues/5212

You could add it to your suppression list.